# "Export to Excel Default" when pasting cells into Google sheet from Excel

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

Sometimes, as I copy data from cells in an Excel sheet (1 or more cells), when I paste the copy into a Google sheet, it will include a first row with the content "Export to Excel Default". For other Excel spreadsheets, the copies happen as expected (without the addition), even into the same Google sheet.

Does anyone know what causes this, and how can I stop it?

I am using desktop version of Excel from Office 365. For the Excel files this occurs with, it happens regardless of whether I copy 1 or more cells; the first one has the strange string. The content of the cells is just strings; for example, a cell containing the string "Module Requirement", when copied into a Google sheet, results in two separate cells (one above the other), containing:

```
Export to Excel Default
Module Requirement
```

This happens regardless of where I paste them into the Google Sheet, both into blank and already filled cells, or even into a new, blank Google Sheet.

In Excel, the cell has type "General", with left, bottom alignment, is font Arial size 10, no bold/italic/etc, automatic font color, no cell fill, cell content NOT wrapped.

Asking Excel to inspect the document only found Document properties that could be removed, and no other problems.

Hmm. After the Inspect and removing the personal information, it no longer has the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I haven't hear about this before. Please add more details like the Excel version that you are using, if the copied cells are using Excel features that are unsupported in Google Sheets, the size of the range copied, if the cells content are values or formulas or they are filled by some Excel feature like a pivot table .

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that under document properties, at File➜Info, the Title property had the text "Export to Excel Default" in it, and removing that text removed the problem.

I don't know why, but whatever text is in the Excel file's Title property gets pasted into Google sheets before the cells that were copied. This is perhaps a better question to ask . . .